# Creating a form with unknown fields and storing those fields into a serialized filed in my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a form that will have both a dynamic set and a known set of fields. I need a way of storing the dynamic fields in the database and I have decided on storing them in a serialized field, as I will not need to search on the data, and I just need it stored and recalled when needed.

```
class MyApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :applicant
    belongs_to :member

    serialize :additional_fields, Hash

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :applicant, :additional_fields
```

I was thinking of having the form return the fields as an additional_fields_attributes and somehow have the model look after storying the hash into the additional_fields section. Im not sure if I have to go as far as using something like method missing to look after this, or if I should scrap the accepts_nested_attributes_for and handle it on my own.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks! Ryan

Answer (score 1):

I just tested what you suggest.

You don't need: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :additional_fields`

Just add in your form html like:

```
<input name="my_application[additional_fields][first]" type="text" /> 
<input name="my_application[additional_fields][second]" type="text" />
```

it will save a Hash with keys: `first` and `second`

You could put in your model an array of fields, say in your User model:

```
FIELDS= ["item1", "item2"]
```

In your view:

```
<% User::FIELDS.each do |field|%>
     <input name="my_application[additional_fields][<%= field %>]" type="text" /> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn those hash keys into methods? For example use my_application.additional_fields.first

Comment: this should answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910326/rails-editing-serialized-data-in-form

Comment: That works if you know that the fields are going to be. In my case the form is dynamically generated, and each application may have different fields. Is there a way to deal with this using something like meta programming to generate the required methods from what is contained in the Serialized Hash?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you expect but my answer is edited. If it doesn't fit, please give details.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this tutorial http://www.kalzumeus.com/2009/11/17/practical-metaprogramming-with-ruby-storing-preferences/ which worked really well.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This was indeed a nice article. For reasons I don't yet understand after a few days of Ruby/Rails programming, I had to scope the serialized "options" variable with "self" in the two metaprogrammed attribute methods. Otherwise options appears to be scoped locally to those methods. I'm on Rails 3 and Ruby 1.8.7.