# Rails3 fields_for on text Hash: not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, erb

I have a rails3 form that allows the user to edit a list of answers, as part of an assessment.
I use a `fields_for` loop to generate each text input:

app/models/assessment.rb :

```
class Assessment < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :answers, Hash   # answers is a t.text field used to store all answers.
end
```

app/view/assessments/new.html.erb :

```
<p>Initialized answers: <%= @assessment.answers %></p>

<% item_counter = 0 %>
<% form.fields_for :answers do |answer_fields| %>
    <% item_id = "item" + item_counter.to_s %>
    <% item_counter = item_counter + 1 %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= answer_fields.label "the appropriate question, omitted for brevity" %>
      <br/>
      <% @assessment.answers[item_id] = "" %>
      <%= answer_fields.text_field item_id, :value => @assessment.answers[item_id] %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**PROBLEM:** The `fields_for` loop does zero iteration, no field gets printed.
( despite "Initialized answers:" showing correctly: {"a"=>143, "b"=>42} )

Comment: as far as I know fields for are used when you have a relation between AR models so I'm not sure why are you trying to render fields for answers with this helper maybe you should write your own helper or render partial

Comment: @Bohdan: It seems possible, judging from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002963#4809844

Comment: it seems that this helper accepts collection as a param could you change it to `<% form.fields_for @assessment.answers do |answer_fields| %>` ?

Comment: @Bohdan: I had tried this first, but it fails saying: undefined method `model_name' for Hash:Class

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should do.  Tested locally.

```
<p>Initialized answers: <%= @assessment.answers %></p>

<% @assessment.answers.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :answers, @assessment.answers[key] do |answer_fields| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= answer_fields.label key %>
        <br/>
        <%= answer_fields.text_field key, :value => value %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! The bounty ends very soon, so I accept before I can check.

Comment: Could not get this to work with the same setup. Managed to make things work using the technique in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899440/creating-a-form-with-unknown-fields-and-storing-those-fields-into-a-serialized-f

Comment: Thanks for the useful post! Small fix, in rails 3 it should be:

<%= form.fields_for ... %>

Answer (score 8):

Turns Hash to OpenStruct object solved my problem.

```
<% form.fields_for :answers, OpenStruct.new(answers) do |answer_fields| %>
<% item_id = "item" + item_counter.to_s %>
<% item_counter = item_counter + 1 %>
<div class="field">
  <%= answer_fields.label "the appropriate question, omitted for brevity" %>
  <br/>
  <% @assessment.answers[item_id] = "" %>
  <%= answer_fields.text_field item_id, :value => @assessment.answers[item_id] %>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, this is the answer ! you saved my day :D

Comment: nice trick to use an OpenStruct in this case. Used it with an hstore-backed field with success.