# Rails: How to read the value entered by the user in a text_field_tag input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have a form with `<%= text_field_tag "mykey" %>`. The user enters `myvalue` and submits. How to get this value when the POST request hits the Rails server?

I can see `myvalue` passing in the POST request:

```
Started POST "/assessments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-08 20:04:41 +0900
  Processing by AssessmentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "mykey"=>"myvalue"}
```

But how can I read this value in my controller?
In `AssessmentsController#create`, first thing I do is log the params, and it is unfortunately empty:

```
logger.debug session[:assessment_params].collect {|k,v| "#{k}: #{v}"}.join
```

*Note: I can not use text_field instead of text_field_tag, because of [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621341/rails3-fields-for-on-text-hash-not-working-as-expected).*

Comment: just a tip you might call it `assetment[mykey]` so it will be a part f assetment hash or `assetment[mykey][]` if you want no have an array of values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your form isn't a model form, which appears to be the case, you just want `params[:mykey]`.

Comment: No worries. Don't forget you can accept the answer as correct, too.